# when to cast objects in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, casting, uinavigationcontroller, subclass

Is there a general rule to casting?

So far I have only casted in objective-c when I want the object to be of the type of a custom super class I created. Such as `class: Car, subclass: Ford` and I cast a `Ford` object to `(Car *)`

However I was going through some sample code and I found this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

    CoursesTableViewController *cvtc = (CoursesTableViewController *) [[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    cvtc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

Why is `nav` casted to a `(UINavigationController *)` when it already is? and same again for `cvtc` but for a custom subclass of a `TableViewController`

Comment: @reformer Storyboard not a nib. I should also note I was viewing a core data example and that NSManagedOBject Subclass was created. I am more interested in why it is casted though.

Comment: It's not the `nav` that is being cast, it's `self.window.rootViewController` that is being cast.

Comment: Not directly related to your question - but if Ford, is a subclass of car, then Ford IS a Car, and a result, you don't need to cast Ford to Car. On the other hand, not all Car objects may be a Ford, so in that case it makes sense to cast a Car to Ford, if you know it is a Ford, and want to make use of Ford specific properties and methods.

Comment: John thats a good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of `self.window.rootViewController` is `UIViewController` not `UINavigationController`. And `UINavigationController` inherits `UIViewController`. That is why it is typecasted.

Similarly, `CoursesTableViewController` is typecasted as return type of `[[nav viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];` is `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is nav casted to a (UINavigationController *) when it already is?

The `self.window.rootViewController` provides the content view of the window.

It will return the resulted content view as `UIViewController`. You may be assigned any class that derived from UIViewController as `self.window.rootViewController`.

So it will be your duty to cast it as per your code.

> same again for cvtc but for a custom subclass of a TableViewController

The above explanation will cover this.